# XML in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

```
<mx:HTTPService id="theXMLtree" url="http://localhost/file.php"/>

<mx:Tree dataProvider="{dp}"></mx:Tree>
```

The file generates the XML, i need to embedeed that info in my tree... how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quickstart for HTTPService

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/httpservice/